# Sequence of close numbers

Tags: number-sequence

I just came up with the following sequence of numbers.

25 26 27 28 30 30 ...

They all seem to be very close to one another... but what is the next number in the sequence? And what is the principle behind it?

--- EDIT ---

The sequence is considered too broad, so I'll add another number to it. The next number is

> 35

But then, what is the number after that?

Comment: There are several perfectly reasonable possibilities in OEIS alone. I think this has to be reckoned too broad, no?

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Wow, I'm impressed by OEIS, which I never consulted before. It's not any of its sequences. I'll add another number to the sequence, if you think it's needed

Answer (score 2):

25,26,27,28,30,30,35,34,43,40,56 etc, is the sequence I found.
it's based on the Fibonacci sequncens of differences.
in odd position 25 27 30 35 43 56, in witch the difference are 2 3 5 8 13.
in even position 26,28,30,34,40 in witch difference are 2 2 4 6 10